# MVC 6 (vNext) UserManager - DI - create user in specific database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm developing multitenant application. I use separate databases for each tenant. UserData are for each tenant in separate database TOO.

My problem is how can i create admin account for each tenant in "custom" database independently on DI. In MVC 5 was possible to instantiate UserManager base on UserStore(connection string). But UserManager in mvc6 depends on HttpContext... No documentation found...
Exist please some way how to do it??? I need in mvc 6 something like this in mvc 5:

```
 UserStore<TenantUser> store = new UserStore<TenantUser>(new TenantDbContext("CONNECTION STRING"));  //!!!  NO POSSIBLE CREATE USER IN CUSTOM DATABASE
        UserManager<TenantUser> t = new UserManager<TenantUser>(store);
        t.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

Update:

```
public class TenantDbContext : IdentityDbContext<TenantUser, TenantRole, Guid>
{
    private string _connectionString { get; set; }
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

    //THIS SUB UNCOMENT ONLY IF CREATE MIGRATIONS (dnx ef...)
    /*  
    public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext> options) : base(options) 
    {
        this._connectionString = "CONNECTION STRING";
    }
    */
    public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext) : base(options)          {                            
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        TenantResolver resolver = new TenantResolver(_contextAccessor, _applicationDbContext);
        string con = resolver.GetConnectionString();
        if (con != string.Empty)
        {
            this._connectionString = con;                            }
        else
        {
            this._connectionString = "CONNECTION STRING"; //Development connection string
        }
    }

    public TenantDbContext()        //Posibility to create TenantDbContext migration and development database with no connectionString in constructor
    {
        //this._connectionString = "CONNECTION STRING";
    }   
    public TenantDbContext(string ConnectionString)
    {
        this._connectionString = ConnectionString;
    }
    public static TenantDbContext Create(string ConnectionString)
    {
        return new TenantDbContext(ConnectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    { 
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);  
    }
```

Comment: There are many ways to solve your problem. **One need to know more information.** Do you defined both connection strings which you need in `appsettings.json`? How you created `TenantDbContext` (manually, by usage of `dnx ef dbcontext scaffold`)? Do you have two contexts (`TenantDbContext1` and `TenantDbContext2`). One uses in ASP.NET 5 typically dependency injection. It allows to register all required contexts in `ConfigureServices` of `Startup.cs` and `new DbContext` will be called by services and forwarded to the constructor of Controller or to every Action of the controller.

Comment: I created two DbContexts: ApplicationDbContext and TenantDbContext. ApplicationDbContext is for all shared data.TenantDbContext depends on subdomain (ConectionString is resolved base on subdomain). For DbContexts is used DI... Problem is how to create user in new database... I cant register TenantDbContext in startup service. it depends on connection strings (many tenants...)

Comment: Could you post more *code fragments*, which explains what you do *exactly*. What you means if you write about "many tenants". Do you have some *specific* list of contexts? In which context you *know* the details (the connection string)? I can show you for example how to change `ConnectionString` of **one** context dynamically, but one could need to close the existing connection and to reopen another one.

Comment: See update please.. many tenants = One TenantDbContext class with multiple connection strings. Connection strings are loaded from database on runtime... See TenantResolver resolver ......

Comment: I have to be away for some hours, thus I posted my answer just now.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I correctly understand you. Let us we forget about the performance and the caching of multiple connections, which already opened to the databases. I suppose that you have *multiple* databases, which have the same schema. You need to access the databases using (sharing) the same database context.

I can suggest you *two* solutions.

**The first solution** consists from registering one context and *reopening* it if the one opened co change the connection string.

Let us you have `TenantDbContext`, which could be opened with different destination databases. For example with

```
@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TenantDb1;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

or

```
@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TenantDb2;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

First of all you remove `OnConfiguring` like

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TenantDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
}
```

which could exist in the definition of `TenantDbContext` and you use the following code in `ConfigureServices` of `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    var connection1 = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TenantDb1;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<TenantDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection1));

    services.AddMvc();
    ...
}
```

In the way you inject `TenantDbContext` with one from the database (`TenantDb1`). Let us the `TenantDbContext` contains some entity set like `Blog` for example. Thus your can define some MVC controller in the following way

```
public class TenantsController : Controller
{
    private TenantDbContext _context;

    public TenantsController (TenantDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index() {
        var con = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();

        // now the con uses either TenantDb2 or TenantDb2
        // con.ConnectionString can be used to get or set the 
        // connection string 
        string needConStr = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TenantDb2;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        if (con.ConnectionString != needConStr) { // can be compared more carefully
            _context.Database.CloseConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = needConStr;
        }

        // get some data from the TenantDbContext
        var blog = _context.Blog.ToList();
        return View(blog);
    }
}
```

**The second solution** don't need to inject any `TenantDbContext` using `DependencyInjection`. Instead of that you need just **add** one simple constructor to `TenantDbContext`:

```
public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions optionsBuilder): base (optionsBuilder)
{
}
```

Such simple constructor will allows you to create the context at any time when you need it:

```
public class TenantsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index() {
        var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        contextOptions.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TenantDb2;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        var context = new BloggingContext(contextOptions.Options);
        context.Database.OpenConnection();

        // get some data from the TenantDbContext
        var blog = context.Blog.ToList();
        return View(blog);
    }
}
```

I used all the connection strings directly in the code. You can easy modify the above code to get all connection strings from the config file `appsettings.json`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I do not use this: public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext> options) : base(options). I use this: public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext) : base(options) .... In Controler is injected TenantDbContext with specific connection string base on url. tenant1.app.com and tenant2.app.com have the same TenantDbContexts with diferent connection strings... Problem was only how to add to each tenant database admin user,

Comment: until UserManager is depend on "url".. Solution is to create instance of UserManager manuály and inject in to constructor my custom UserStore. Rest of UserManager's Ctor  is injected from DI.

Comment: I will get connection strings from the config file according you. In config can be connection string for development database or for demo, until each tenant's specific connection string can be resolved on the fly (DI)...

Comment: @MiroslavSiska: I don't use Individual User Accounts myself and thus I understood your problem just as a common database problem. I'm not sure that it helps you, but in general, you should have just the database, which you access with respect of DbContext. Thus it should be not important whether you hold Users and Roles inside or not. I hope that it will help you in some way. If it will not help then you can try to address the question to an specialist in asp.net 5 identity 3.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
1. CreateCustomUserStore

```
public class TenantUserStore : UserStore<TenantUser, TenantRole, TenantDbContext, Guid>
{
    public TenantUserStore(TenantDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null): base(context, describer)
    {  
    }
}
```

And here is code how to instantiate UserManager with custom database:

```
IUserStore<TenantUser> CustomStore = new TenantUserStore(new TenantDbContext(coonection), null);    

UserManager<TenantUser> manager = new UserManager<TenantUser>(CustomStore, _optionsAccessor, _passwordHasher, _userValidators,
                    _passwordValidators, _keyNormalizer, _errors, _services, _logger, _contextAccessor);
```

And DI used only for rest of UserManager Constructor:

```
       public class TenantsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;        
    private readonly IOptions<IdentityOptions> _optionsAccessor;
    private readonly IPasswordHasher<TenantUser> _passwordHasher;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TenantUser>> _userValidators;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TenantUser>> _passwordValidators;
    private readonly ILookupNormalizer _keyNormalizer;
    private readonly IdentityErrorDescriber _errors;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
    private readonly ILogger<UserManager<TenantUser>> _logger;


    public TenantsController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, 
         IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
         IPasswordHasher<TenantUser> passwordHasher,
         IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TenantUser>> userValidators,
         IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TenantUser>> passwordValidators,
         ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
         IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
         IServiceProvider services,
         ILogger<UserManager<TenantUser>> logger


        )
    {
         _optionsAccessor = optionsAccessor;
        _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
        _userValidators = userValidators;
        _passwordValidators = passwordValidators;
        _keyNormalizer = keyNormalizer;
        _errors = errors;
        _services = services;
        _logger = logger;            
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
```